# Define $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sqrt{n}$ if $n\le x \le n+(1/n^2))$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Define $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{n} & \text{if $n\le x \le n+\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ where $n \ge 1$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
Show that $f$ is integrable with respect to Lebesgue measure but $f^2$ is not.

Comment: Ending with the words "Show that" makes it look as if you're passing on to us a homework problem without giving us any evidence that you've understood it enough to ask a question about it.  Can you ask a question about it?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I will be honest and say that I am a graduate student, just beginning and analysis has never been my subject. I'm studying for finals and my instructor asked us to review several questions, this being one. Most of them, i dont even know where to begin, i have  definitons and theorems to use from my text but i struggle a lot with using them. I'm not sure how to use the definition of the Lebesgue integral and Im assuming that to show f^2 is not would be a matter of showing that that step function disapears with the new criteria

Comment: The point of the problem is to show that $\int_{\mathbb R} |f|<\infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb R} |f|^2=\infty$.  You don't really need to know much about the Lebesgue integral.  You really only need to know that it's the same as the Riemann integral except with $f$ is not Riemann-integrable.

Comment: @MichaelHardy My text references teh Riemann-Lebesgue theorem that states if f:R to R is lebesgue integrable, then the limit as n goes to infinity of the integral of f(x)cos(nx)dlamda(x)=limite as n goes to infinity of the integral of f(x)sin(nx)dlamda(x)=0 and using another theorem that states, let f be an integrable function, and let epsilon>0.Then there exists a function phi element L s.t. fabs(f-phi)dmu< epsilon.So if I can show limit of the integral abs(fn-f)dmu=0 holds, im done. is that tight? Which im assuming is what Sahand referred to by showing convergence

Comment: There's no need for trigonometric functions here.  Just notice that $\int_n^{n+n^{-2}} f(x)\,dx$ ${}=\int_n^{n+n^{-2}} \sqrt{n}\,dx$ ${}=\sqrt{n}/n^2$, so $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\,dx$ is the sum of that over all integers $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the definition of Lebesgue integrals to show that the integral of $f$ is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$ and similarly the integral of $f^2$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$. Which one of these converges? Which one doesn't? And why?

Comment: following my thought process above, is that what you meant by showing convergence? @sahand

Comment: The first summation converges by the comparison test, the second one diverges(harmonic series). I'm not sure what this tells me though. This course is the first time i've dealt with Lebesgue integrals and I dont quite understand them @sahand

Comment: I think using Riemann sums for this problem might defeat the purpose a bit. As mentioned, try to use the definition of the Lebesgue integral directly to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f^2 d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$. After that, the convergence results that you noted give you exactly the result you're looking for.

As for using the definition of the Lebesgue integral, start by noticing what the measure of the interval $[n, n + \frac{1}{n^2}]$ is, and what the value of $f$ is on that interval.